# onscreen keyboard in multiple languages

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, internationalization, onscreen-keyboard

I occasionally want to type in character sets other than those on my physical keyboard and it seems like onboard should be a good solution for this. I have a few languages installed on my system, but clicking on the language key (  on the right of the keyboard) only shows me English, the active language on the system. How do I get other languages to appear on that list without changing my entire system language?

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10

I'm currently using the onscreen keyboard (see: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html ), which it turns out it separate from onboard.

[image: An onscreen keyboard with a language selection menu open which only shows english]

This image shows the keyboard with it's language menu. Clicking on the "Region and Language Settings" goes to system preferences, which I installed the languages I want. I know they're on the system because I accidentally, briefly set my system language to one of them. They don't show on the keyboard's menu.

Comment: Hello. I do not know what that blue spot is. Do you not have a button at the top right on mine 20.04 next to the network arrows for language selection for keyboard?

Comment: I don't seem to

Comment: apparently the flag button in the onscreen keyboard can change language, according to the link you posted. Did you try that?

Comment: Are you sure you have other languages installed on your user account? How did you install them?

Comment: I've edited my question to include answers to the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is to edit keyboard sources in your settings to add the kind of keyboard you want to see.  Put your normal language at the top of the list and additional ones below it.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en

Note that when you select the alternative keyboard, this will change how the system interprets your physical keyboard, so you'll need to switch back before typing.  You can do this using the on-screen keyboard. See here for how to access it. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html.en